# Github commit fails only after NPM install is run

Tags: node.js, github

/Github Beginner. I'm trying to get to grips with Github, I understand most of the basics (I think). However I'm totally stumped by an error message I'm receiving when I try to commit some changes.

As context, I forked and then cloned the flux/alt repo https://github.com/goatslacker/alt. I then copied one of the example projects but made some changes to use webpack rather than browserify. Committing/synching these changes worked fine. But now when I make local changes I get the error message **'env: node: No such file or directory
 (1)'**

I explored it a bit further, and it seems this error message only appears after I have NPM installed the package.json, i.e. if I take a fresh clone of the repo, I can make changes and commit fine - as long as I do not NPM install.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by an NPM install of the root package.json, so to resolve it I moved everything essential to the project directory package.json and only NPM installed this one.